# Deep links only work in browser and e-mail. Facebook Messenger just opens them in its integrated browser

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I managed to integrate **deep/universal links** into my web view application, however they only work if the links are opened in the **browser or in an e-mail**.

If the link is in i.e. **Facebook Messenger, it doesn't**. I guess because Messenger opens the site in an integrated browser, thus the event can't escape from Messenger to the OS level. But this is just a theory.

Is there a way to make deep links work with links i.e. in Messenger?

Comment: No, universal links don't work in embedded browsers. You will probably also find they don't work from alternate browsers like Chrome

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh, shoot, you are right, even Chrome doesn't let it work if I enter it in the address bar. At least it works with links.

Answer (score 0):

Universal links don't work for certain apps (like Facebook, etc..).
For such cases, you should consider a webpage as a fallback..
Meaning, that when opening the universal link, show a basic page with a button that will lead the user to the app (via urlScheme) or to appstore (if the urlScheme opening fails).